# Python does not close open files

Tags: python

I have a Python script that opens a lot (over 2 million) small text files in a for loop. However, it stops when I reach approximately 150'000 files, which indicates for me that I reached the default limit of open files in the Linux kernel.

But, I'm closing the files, so I'm not sure why I hit that limit. The interesting part breaks down to that:

```
import os

files = os.listdir('/var/tmp/files')

for file in files:
    fd = open('/var/tmp/files/{}'.format(file), 'r')
    content = fd.readlines()

    # Doing stuff

    fd.close()
```

The code works, but apparently it doesn't close files. At first i tried the better `with open()` statement, but that didn't work either.

Why doesn't Python close the files?

Comment: Are you sure it's that Python isn't closing the files, and it's not something else?

Comment: It should close the files, unless you have a `break` or `continue` in the 'Doing Stuff' block.

Comment: can you please show the traceback/error/logs?

Comment: "*it stops*": Are you getting an error message? Please post the error message, if so. File descriptor exhaustion should be clearly indicated by an `IOError` with `errno=ENFILE`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys. The problem was that my user had no access to one specific file. So, Python did everything as it should.

I expected that it had to do with Linux' max number of open files as the number of processed files were really near to that max value. It was a coincidence, though.

Thanks for all your help, and sorry for the noise.

Comment: Glad you posted that - I was just replicating the situation and was about to report that I couldn't reproduce!

Answer (score -1):

There must be something else happening in your code. Check the status of your file object before you reopen the file:

```
import os

files = os.listdir('/var/tmp/files')
fileClosed=True
for file in files:
    if fileClosed:
        with open('/var/tmp/files/{}'.format(file), 'r') as fd:
            content = fd.readlines()
        ## DO Stuff
    else:
        print "File not closed properly"
        break
    fileClosed = fd.closed
```

Comment: Could you comment why this is downvoted, maybe I can understand and improve my future answers.

Comment: I downvoted because you don't provide an answer, just a method of diagnosis. This would've been better in a comment.

Comment: @JoeSmart That's a bit unfair. None of the current answers offer a solution, as the problem is almost certainly in the "doing stuff" area and in addition there is another answer that in my opinion is pure gobbledygook!

Comment: Then state it in a comment. If you need more info then state it. Just because other answers don't solve the problem doesn't mean that it's suddenly okay.

Comment: I downvoted because it does something pretty unhelpful if there are millions of files IMHO.  Once one file close fails, `fileClosed` will remain `False` and a huge stream of `"File no closed properly"` would be output to terminal or output file.  You can edit it to make better, I guess - a `break` in the `else` block would do it.  It would still only be a diagnosis aid, though

Comment: @JoeSmart : I wrote this in an answer because I also rewrote other parts of the code for better diagnosis. This is because, even though the OP has written that he has used with open, I wanted to make sure that in case there is some break occurring in the yet undisclosed code, the file still "closes", and we can get closer to establishing the source of the error.

Comment: @JRichardSnape: I agree, and it is a useful suggestion, implemented.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this will solve the problem, but try. It may be that the program is opening multiple files in the same variable or loop prevents the program to close the files.

```
import os

files = os.listdir('/var/tmp/files')
fd = list()

for file in files:
    if files > 100000:
        break
    fd.append(open('/var/tmp/files/{}'.format(file), 'r'))
    content = fd[file].readlines()

    # Doing stuff
for file in files:
    if files > 100000:
        break
    fd[files].close()
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that you use multiprocess or something in your "Doing Stuff" block. You can assume that you will always face problems related file descriptor when you use multiprocess, so you need more attention.

To solve this problem, simply don't open file before you start another process. You should open file after another process started.